# Regex to test static URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a JavaScript program to download media files, but it needs to get the actual direct address of the file, not a dynamic link with URL parameters.

So for example

`https://tools.woolyss.com/html5-audio-video-tester/?u=www.groovydomain.com/gallery/music/ORIGINAL/Pink%20Floyd/The%20Dark%20Side%20of%20the%20Moon/09%20Eclipse.mp3`

should fail, but

`https://www.groovydomain.com/gallery/music/ORIGINAL/Pink%20Floyd/The%20Dark%20Side%20of%20the%20Moon/09%20Eclipse.mp3`

should work.

I'm going about it by excluding links that have a question mark in them, implying they're dynamic. So far I've gotten to exclude question marks using `^((?!\?).)+$` but is it possible to combine that with detecting file extensions?

I'm using `\/.+\.(aac|flac|gifv|mp3|mp4|oga|ogg|opus|wav|webm)` to detect supported formats.

Is there a way to combine these so that it only matches static links that end with these extensions? I only need to test here, not extract any part of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(^((?!\?).)+\.(aac|flac|gifv|mp3|mp4|oga|ogg|opus|wav|webm))
```

Updated regex for your use. It will not match

```
https://tools.woolyss.com/html5-audio-video-tester/?u=www.groovydomain.com/gallery/music/ORIGINAL/Pink%20Floyd/The%20Dark%20Side%20of%20the%20Moon/09%20Eclipse.mp3
```

but will match for

```
https://www.groovydomain.com/gallery/music/ORIGINAL/Pink%20Floyd/The%20Dark%20Side%20of%20the%20Moon/09%20Eclipse.mp3
```

Comment if you need any further customization.

Comment: When I try it with regex.test() or match(), it errors out saying 'Nothing to repeat'.

Comment: Can you please create fiddle for it as problem from comment is not explanatory?

Comment: Found the problem, had to further escape the ?. Thanks again.